# Python importing tensorflow returns "Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 key"

Tags: python, 20.04, cuda, tensorflow

I am a linux newcomer trying to set up tensorflow with GPU for Python on Pop!_os 20.04. I tried using the proposed Pop!_os apt packages for this but they didn't work for me.

After a lot of struggle on my own and possible apt pollution, I managed to install Tensorflow with CUDA and cuDNN by following this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/1251052

Although Python's tensorflow seems to properly recognize my GPU, right after importing the library I get this weird message:

```
Python 3.8.2 (default, Apr 27 2020, 15:53:34) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 key
>>>
```

Can someone tell me what this means or give me some clue on what should I do (maybe I can take that as a warning and live with it), please?

Not sure if this qualifies as an Ubuntu question but since I followed an Ubuntu guide to reach this point and Pop is Ubuntu-based it just felt right to ask here.

System info (advice on what to include/not include here next time is appreciated):

```
OS: Pop!_OS 20.04 LTS x86_64
Host: ERAZER X6807 MD61178 Standard 
Kernel: 5.4.0-7634-generic
Packages: 2407 (dpkg)
Shell: bash 5.0.16
Resolution: 1920x1080 
DE: GNOME
WM: Mutter
Terminal: gnome-terminal 
CPU: Intel i7-8750H (12) @ 4.100GHz
GPU: Intel UHD Graphics 630
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 Mobile
Memory: 15868MiB
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think it has nothing to do with TensorFlow. Try: `tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')`, if it does not display any error, it means everything is okay with your installation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [X11: Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 key](https://askubuntu.com/questions/984359/x11-invalid-mit-magic-cookie-1-key)

Comment: @singrium I already tried that line, which returned a bunch of things and a final line of [PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')], from which I guess the GPU is okay (I checked and GPU0 is the Nvidia's). About the second comment, I checked that page and I honesty lack the knoweledge to understand it fully: I understood that entering "xhost +local:" would grant the access of the GPU to my monitor so I entered it on the shell, but no change after importing inside python

Comment: The output you got confirms that TensorFlow can see your GPU and use it. So no problem with the installation. The message you're getting is probably related to the display

Comment: @singrium I launched a random application (discord) with the dedicated graphics and it worked as always, so the GPU can actually access the display for normal use (in other words I guess I did not break anything important). While I still do not get why the warning pops out or what it means, it seems I can ignore it for now at my own risk. Thanks a lot!